# Mock a nested function with input arguments in Python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, patch

My folder structure

```
main.py
    class Class1
        generate_columns()
        column_api()
utilities.py
    class Class2
        get_response()
```

I want to mock `column_api()` function in `class Class1`.

The function signature is as follows:

```
class Class1:
    def generate_columns():
        calls `get_response()` from `class Class2` and returns response

    def column_api(data=List[Dict]]):
        resp = self.generate_columns(data)
        for item in resp:
            if data["name"] == item["name"]:
                ret.append(item)
    return ret
```

I would like to mock `column_api`. Here's the test I have so far:

```
def test_column_api():
    testClass = Class1()
    mock_response = [{"id":"1", "name":"test1"}]
    load_data = [{"id":"1", "name":"test1"}, {"id":"2", "name":"test2"}]
    with patch("package.main.Class1.generate_columns") as api_mock:
        api_mock.return_value = mock_response

        result = testClass.column_api(load_data)
        assert len(result) == 1
```

It fails here with an `AssertionError`. The returned list is always empty no matter how much I try. But ideally, according to my function definition, the returned list should have one dictionary whose name matches with a name in the response object.

I am very new to `Mock` and `patch` concepts in Python. After reading through various posts on SO and the actual docs on `Mock`, I could come until this far. I think my `api_mock` is not being utilized by `column_api` function. I think that's where the problem is but I am not sure how to make `column_api` recognize `api_mock`. Any help on this is much appreciated! Hope my function definitions are clear here but I am happy to include any other information that I may have missed.

Thank you so much in advance. I have been breaking my head over this for quite sometime now. Hoping to find some answer here.

Answer (score 0):

A good colleague of mine helped me with the solution and I am posting it down below. This solution worked for my purposes.

```
@pytest.fixture
def mocked_gen_col(monkeypatch):

    def mock_gen_technical(*args, **kwargs):
        return [
            {"name": "a"},
            {"name": "b"}
        ]
    monkeypatch.setattr(Class1, "generate_columns", mock_gen_technical)

def test_technical_column_api(mocked_gen_col):
    data = [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "a"
    }]

    list = Class1().column_api(data=data)
    assert list[0]["name"] == "a"
    assert len(list) == 1
```